# How to reload JKExpandTableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, jkexpandtableview

I am using [JKExpandTableView](https://github.com/jackkwok/JKExpandTableView) and I want to reload JKExpandTableview. Currently Im calling **reloadData** method on **JKExpandTableView object** but it will not call data source delegate method. Thanks.

My header file is like below:

```
#import "JKExpandTableView.h"

@interface IncidentsViewController : UIViewController <JKExpandTableViewDelegate, JKExpandTableViewDataSource>

@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet JKExpandTableView * expandTableView;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray * dataModelArray;
-(void)refreshIncidentsModule;
@end
```

And my IncidentsController.m is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view
  [self initializeSampleDataModel];
  self.expandTableView.tableViewDelegate = self;
  self.expandTableView.dataSourceDelegate = self;
  [self deviceOrientationDidChangeNotification:nil];
}

-(void)refreshIncidentsModule
{
  [self initializeSampleDataModel];
  [self.expandTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Can you post your current codes? Thanks!

Comment: @Rahul : Did you find any solution for this? If yes, please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

in your `viewDidLoad` method set delegate and datasource.something like followings:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.expandTableView.tableViewDelegate = self;
    self.expandTableView.dataSourceDelegate = self;
}
```

Comment: Its already there:
[self.expandTableView setDataSourceDelegate:self];
[self.expandTableView setTableViewDelegate:self];

Comment: @RahulDange when you call reloadData, nothing happens to the datasource methods?

Comment: Actually for the very first time everything is working fine. But when I try to reload JKExpandTableView afterwards it will not call any of datasource methods.

Comment: you'd better update your question to post more code, especially where you modified. without code, its hard to help you.

Comment: @Chancy Could you help me out with JKExpandableTableview here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071132/add-custom-cell-to-jkexpandtableview-as-child-cell-in-ios