# Add custom Cell to JKExpandtableview as Child Cell in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, jkexpandtableview

I've been facing problem to add custom cell in **JKExpandableTableView** ,How Can I add Custom Cell as a child,Any Help will be appreciated ,Thanks.

Sorry for my english.
I'd like to achieve output like [image: This Screenshot]

**Note:** I'm using this Library [JKExpandableTableView](https://github.com/jackkwok/JKExpandTableView) everything is working fine.

Comment: Can any one help me?,Any help will be appreciated

Comment: it would be much better if you could post your code snippet and the screenshot.

Comment: @chancy Could you help me out ?

Comment: @Chancy would you help me?

Comment: Please post your code and clarify what exactly is not working.

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv I want to achieve this kind of output using JKExpandableTableview,See my Screenshot And if possible tell me How can I add my custom cell as a Sub Cell

Comment: Why do you use JKExpandableTableview? Can you use something else?

Comment: Yes.. I could If I would have better one

Answer (score 0):

`JKExpandTableView` is a subclass of `UITableView`.

You must implement delegate of `UITableView`.

**ex)**

Example class

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@end`

@implementation CustomCell
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {

        [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    }

    return self;

}

@end
```

You implement delegate for CustomCell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *identifierCell = @"CustomCell";

        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierCell];

        if(cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:invitationCell];

        }

   return cell;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the following link. The creator himself answered the question 
https://github.com/jackkwok/JKExpandTableView/issues/5

> jackkwok commented on 9 Aug 2014 
>   Hi Bruno, Thanks! You may need to
>   subclass both of them. What kind of customizations do you want to do?